# DocuSign Integration with Multiple Prod Accounts

Tags: docusignapi

We've a Business requirement to download Documents from Multiple DocuSign Accounts.

Is it possible to map one developer integration key for Multiple Prod DocuSign Accounts?
Is there a way (Free/Paid Service) to create integration key directly in Prod DocuSign Account?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYPqC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your second question - no, you can only crated Integration Keys (IKs) in demo/developer account.

Now, you may be confused a bit about the relationship between IKs and accounts.

Once an IK is approved in prod ([go-live process](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/)) then it can be used with any account in prod. It can be used not just with the account that created it but with any other account, completely unrelated to the organization.

So, if that's your need, you're in luck, you don't need to do anything different.

Create an IK in demo. Get the app working in demo (Developer account) and test it there.

Once your IK is approved (passed go-live) it can be used in production with many different accounts.

Comment: Once your IK is approved (passed go-live) it can be used in production with many different accounts. -- This will meet our requirements.

Comment: One Question: If the Integration key goes Live for one Production account and again if I want to use the same IK for other Production account, `Will IK's status change to Pending Approval again and again Will it take 3 business days?`

Comment: no, once approved, that's it, you can use it in production with any account.

Comment: Hi, we promoted our IK to One production account. I want to promote the same IK to another Production account, But I don't see the option. Please suggest...  Attached screenshot in the description above.

Comment: There's no need to do that, one your IK is in production - it can be used with all accounts. Even if you don't see it in the other account, it can still be used with that account.

Comment: Hi Inbar, Can you provide more information on how to use same IK in multiple Production accounts. Basically we want to implement Authorization Code Grant (OAuth) for getting Access Token for API calls. If I don't map the IK in those multiple production accounts, How can I get access token using OAuth?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/
During Auth Code Grant user has to log in and they can log into any account and that account can use with any IK.

Comment: Understood... Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Inbar, one qq: Is there any limitation on Download Documents API for Personal paid account? We do see limitation for sending documents but don't find limitation for downloading. https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing. Can you please suggest...

Comment: I think you may be referring to either polling limitation or hourly API limits. Both these limits are very different then the envelope limit which is a plan/purchase limit. There's a default 1000/hour API calls hourly limit and the polling limit which basically say you cannot query THE SAME envelope again and again and again.
You can download as many documents as you send for sure.

Comment: Got it... Thank you

Comment: @InbarGazit hey Inbar, your this answer is what we did but unfortunately we are not able to use single IK which is already GoLive for sending documents for eSign of other unrelated accounts. Basically we have a CRM for which we have docusign pro account and we have completed our GoLive process. Now we have flow where we are getting consent from our client using redirect consent flow. After that we auth token of consent and we retrieve access token for the client. But when we try to send eSign request with this access token we get INVALID_USER error. Our IK account is separate from clients.Help

Comment: please ask your question separately, as it's a different issue. Your issue is a mismatch between the user and the account, or you use a user from the wrong environment