# Docusign integration App not allowing to send cross account documents for eSign. INVALID_USER error

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

We have done one CRM integration where we as an CRM have our own docusign pro account.

We completed the GoLive process successfully and have all required data like Integration key, Account Id, Client Id and Secret Key for App.

Now this CRM integration will be used as an mediator for our clients who will have their own purchased docusign accounts.

So till now we have 2 accounts,

1. CRM Integration docusign account with GoLive status.
2. Client account to send their own documents for eSign through our CRM integration.

What we have achieved till now?

1. We completed the consent flow where we redirect our clients to docusign consent page where they provide consent to our app by login into their docusign account. In this flow we use CRM integration account id in URL which takes our client for consent page. On confirm the client will be redirected back to CRM with auth code attached in redirect URL.
2. We use this auth code to get access token for this client. We use CRMs account id, Integration App secret key and clients auth code to get the access token. We are successful in this too. We get clients access token. No Issues.
3. Now when our client is trying to send a document for eSign using the access token received in step 2 above, the docusign throws an error saying INVALID_USER.

I have referred to this post [Simillar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66639980/docusign-integration-with-multiple-prod-accounts) it kind of approves of what we are trying to achieve but it is failing with error.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain and make sure it's clear.
The IK ([Integration Key](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/configure-app/)) is global for the entire environment. By environment I mean either the [developer environment](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/account/), or the production environment. When you [went live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/) and completed the process using a production environment - you made your IK available for any account and any user in the production environment.

Now, when you [get an access token to](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) make API calls, this token is for a specific **userId**. The **userId** can be a member of one ore more accounts as showed in this diagram:
[image]

The **userId** is provided by the user logging in when given the option to consent. So when you doing your consent flow, there's a web browser and user that logs in, that is the **userId** that consent.
Separately, when you request a token using [JWT grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/), you provide a userId, that userId is a GUID for a unique user in the system.
This GUID must be for the same exact production user that gave consent. That's first thing to confirm.
Now, if you already have an access token to make API calls, when you make a specific API call, you need to provide an **accountID**. That's another GUID representing an account, not a user. The **userId** that was provided to the JWT Grant flow must represent a user that has a membership (it is a member of) in the account for which you provided a GUID (a user can be a member of more than one account). That is the second thing to check.
Lastly, there's a **baseURI** that is used to make API calls and it can be different for different accounts. You need to also confirm you are using the correct one.

Comment: Thanks @Inbar for you reply. In our case both the Integration account (where the GoLive app is) is different completely from clients docusign account. They are not same company, orgnization, child of any common parent. Completely detached. No LINK between them. Will that work?

Comment: Also we are not using JWT but only Auth Grant type.

Comment: yes, it will work

Comment: If you are using Auth Code Grant, I don't understand how you get to this issue at all. Every user has to log in, right? when do you get the error?

Comment: Yes, user gives consent by login and we recieve auth code which we use to get access token. This works very well in developer account but when we went GoLive and tried same flow with user who is not part of our organization and belongs to different account altogether we got error from docusign saying INVALID_USER. On GoLive account getting auth consent and access token perfectly works fine but when we use that access token to send for eSign it fails.

Comment: I still don't get when you get INVALID_USER? when you make API call? when you ask for consent? when you try to do what exactly?

Comment: I suspect you a mixing developer account and prod account. The user from one env (the userID/GUID) cannot be used in the other env.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243473/discussion-between-scanqr-and-inbar-gazit).

Comment: Sorry, I can't do chat, if you need immediate support I recommend you contact DocuSign Developer Support